# How should I define instance variables made up of multiple words?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

When researching how to declare instance variables properly in Ruby, all I could find were instance variables with a single name:

```
@variable
```

But the instance variable I want to use is comprised of two words. I was wondering how to declare this instance variable? Is it:

```
@instanceVariable
```

or:

```
@instance_variable
```

or something completely different?

As I'm new I want to make sure I get convention correct to make me a better programmer.

Comment: Using the right case for variables won't necessarily make you a better programmer, but it will help make your code more maintainable for others. And, BTW, it's "Ruby" when talking about the language because it's a proper name, and "ruby" when showing a sample of a command to be run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common practise among Ruby programmers is to use the snake case notation for variable names, i.e. `@instance_variable`. See, for example, the [GitHub style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) or [the Unofficial Ruby usage guide](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml).

Comment: +1. Follow the style guides and don't let coding techniques leak in from other languages.

Comment: thanks for this, i came from java. It keeps creeping into my Ruby code, as you can see above.